# "Display driver has stopped responding and has recovered" when playing Mortal Kombat X?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

I have this happen all the time when playing Mortal Kombat X. The screen freezes up, the game crashes and then I get a popup display ing the error above: Display Driver has Stopped Working.

[image: screenshot of crashed client and Nvidia popup]

The Mortal Kombat process stays active (despite the window being closed) and I have to manually kill it in Task Manager.

I am apparently not the only one experiencing this issue:

- http://steamcommunity.com/app/307780/discussions/0/618459405708624616/
- http://steamcommunity.com/app/307780/discussions/0/618459405707456032/

Does anyone know of a fix/workaround for this yet?

I have up to date Nvidia drivers. This issue has never occured for me in any game, even in GTA V max settings, or CS: GO high settings. Only MkX on low settings, so I can get a decent FPS crashes for me. Win 8.1.  Compatibility mode does nothing but prevent the game from launching, running as admin changes little.

Comment: I think this is perfectly clear & on topic here, but we could do with some more info: What have you tried? Can you run the game in compatibility mode, or with Administrator privileges? Have you run a 'verify integrity' of  the game? Are your graphics drivers up to date? Have you installed the correct version of Direct X?

Comment: If this is a "fairly common issue for nvidia users" as you did in fact write in your first comment, then the problem is likely a bug in the NVIDIA drivers (or hardware) and you'll have to wait either until NVIDIA fixes it or the Mortal Kombat X developers release a patch that works around the NVIDIA bug. I don't know what other kind of response you're expecting.

Comment: Comments cleaned up. Please keep the comments civil.

Comment: FYI, MKX is notoriously bad on PC but is going to have a patch soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So unlike what others here have been saying; this has been confirmed to be a game issue (not an Nvidia issue) that was fixed by the developers (Netherrealm Studios) [in the today's 15GB patch:](http://www.reddit.com/r/MortalKombat/comments/34yjto/pc_patch_rolled_out_15_gb/)

> - Added the free Klassic Sub-Zero costume.
>
>   ## Display drivers should no longer crash during online play.
> - **A crash will no longer occur after a full rotation of players in the lobby during Round Robin matches.**
> - **Fixed a crash that some users experienced during the first QTE in the story.**
> - **Game no longer crashes when players attempt to join a game through Steam or in a room.**
> - **Fixed startup crash on high end systems (those with > 8 cores).**
> - **Fixed a crash that would occur during recorded match playback**.
> - Save data safety check to try to eliminate save data loss.
> - Fix to prevent save game data from being corrupted while closing the game.
> - Walk away animations now appear at the end of the character selection process.
> - The levers in Shao Khan's Tomb will now activate.
> - Shinnok's Flick Trick Fatality no longer experiences a significant framerate drop.
> - Functionality is no longer lost while watching a match replay.
> - Pre-game lobbies will populate 10 players into Faction Battle matches.
> - Kombat Kards will now display correct Icons, Backgrounds, and Borders in a KOTH match.
> - Fatality inputs no longer change into QTE inputs during in Online Tower Battles.
> - Game no longer desynchronizes when a player selects a character that their opponent has not unlocked.
> - D'Vorah's cape no longer moves when she's killed.
> - **Game no longer freezes when opponent in online closes the game**.
> - Title remains responsive while story cinematics are loading.
> - Fixed leaderboards and kombat kards not updating past the top players.
> - After entering Replays with the controller the Player can use the keyboard when watching a replay from an online match.
> - Loading screens now display before progress bar fills up.
> - Diagonal arrows are shown instead of keys when Alternate Control is enabled.
> - Sometimes saving a Custom1 preset displayed as being saved for Custom1-4 in the character select and pause menu controls screens.
> - The UI arrows will now switch sides on a tagged move when the character switched position with his opponent.
> - Chat room names will now display properly (instead of SteamIDs.)
> - Fixed input callouts when switching between keyboard and USB controller after entering a KOTH match.
> - Additional graphical fidelity options.

Answer (score 1):

This message popped out every few minutes. That was really driving me crazy.

I did some research online and found there are some workable solutions for me from this post of [how to fix display driver stopped responding and has recovered issue on Windows](http://www.drivethelife.com/windows-drivers/how-to-fix-display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-on-windows-10-8-7-xp-vista.html). Well, now I can play games smoothly.

Comment: @Robotnick, not only is this spam for commercial malware [and a known cross-site spam source](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=drivethelife&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search), but [**it is link only and hence not an answer!**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  The spam flags were declined improperly, but this post should have been deleted as NAA, even if the spam was not noticed.